# How to speed up Alfresco Share development

Tags: share, development-environment, alfresco

I'm developing and performing some customization on Share. My IDE is Eclipse Juno and workspace is made up of the next elements:

- alfresco web project
- extensions Java project
- share web project

Both alfresco and share web projects are deployed in separate Tomcat instances, this way I can slightly speed up my development tasks by restarting only the Tomcat instance where Share is deployed.

My extensions Java project has the same structure as the Eclipse project proposed by Alfresco. Y the provided Ant tasks for compiling, compressing JavaScript files, packaging and deploying the resultant JAR file in Tomcat.

I'm developing some new JavaScript client-side widgets, which means every time I make a change I have to stop Tomcat, launch Ant build script and start again so as I have to do it very often, you can guess what a pain it is becoming. I was just wondering if there exist any way to speed up development tasks on Share. How do Alfresco developers team do it? What kind of environment do they set up?

I was thinking about creating a new Ant target which hot deploys extension project's content into deployed Share web project, taking into account paths of course; that mechanism must allow the reverse operation by the way. Would that be viable? The idea would be to have a similar deploy mechanism as when you  develop regular web projects: when you make any change you just push the "Publish" button and the changes are populated into the server.

I would like to know some tips and ideas, specifically from Alfresco developers team if possible.

PS: I have already read https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=44850 and https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=18749.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is the solution that is working 100% as I expected. I came up with this after the answers of @erik-b and @jorn-horstmann and taking into account some posts I have read.

So basically I have the next Ant target which hot deploys the content of my Share extensions Java project:

```
<!--
    Hot copy individual files into appropriate deployment folder (e.g. $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/share)
-->
<target name="hotdeploy-tomcat-share" depends="clean, prepare, build-jar" description="Hot copy individual files into appropriate deployment folder (e.g. $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/share)">
    <echo message="Generating and deploying JAR file with custom configuration files" />
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${jar.name}">
        <!-- Only including configuration XML files such as share-config-custom.xml -->
        <fileset dir="${build.jar.dir}" includes="**/META-INF/*.xml" />
    </jar>
    <copy todir="${tomcat.share.deployment.path}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <fileset file="${dist.dir}/${jar.name}" />
    </copy>

    <echo message="Hot deploying Share files" />
    <copy todir="${tomcat.share.deployment.path}/WEB-INF/classes" includeEmptyDirs="false">
        <fileset dir="${build.jar.dir}">
            <patternset refid="hotdeploy-tomcat-patternset" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Auto-reloading modules feature must be disabled, otherwise every time you execute the above Ant target Tomcat will reload Share and other web apps deployed. Additionally, I believe it is also possible to hot deploy in the $TOMCAT_HOME/shared/ directory but I haven't tried it out yet.

The Java project I'm using for developing my extensions is this model project: http://code.google.com/p/share-extras/wiki/SampleProject. There is the full build script with the other targets required.

I'm also using this in my share-config-custom.xml:

```
   <!-- Global config section -->
   <config replace="true">
      <flags>
         <!--
            Developer debugging setting to turn on DEBUG mode for client scripts in the browser
         -->
         <client-debug>true</client-debug>

         <!--
            LOGGING can always be toggled at runtime when in DEBUG mode (Ctrl, Ctrl, Shift, Shift).
            This flag automatically activates logging on page load.
         -->
         <client-debug-autologging>false</client-debug-autologging>
      </flags>
   </config>

   <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="WebFramework">
      <web-framework>
         <!-- SpringSurf Autowire Runtime Settings -->
         <!-- 
              Developers can set mode to 'development' to disable; SpringSurf caches,
              FreeMarker template caching and Rhino JavaScript compilation.
         -->
         <autowire>
            <!-- Pick the mode: "production" or "development" -->
            <mode>development</mode>
         </autowire>

         <!-- Allows extension modules with <auto-deploy> set to true to be automatically deployed -->
         <module-deployment>
            <mode>manual</mode>
            <enable-auto-deploy-modules>true</enable-auto-deploy-modules>
         </module-deployment>
      </web-framework>
   </config>
```

The last XML snippet avoids to refresh webscripts after any change performed on an FTL page, for example.

I have also performed some tests with JRebel but after my experience I would say it doesn't helps a lot in Share development.

There is also interesting stuff in the next articles:

http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/kevinr/2010/04/07/developer-tips-for-alfresco-share-33/

http://techblog.zabuchy.net/2012/debugging-javascript-in-alfresco/

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 8):

Two things that speeds up things a lot:

- Invest in a jrebel license for class reloading without server restart http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/
- Construct ant tasks that copy webscripts to the target folder and reloads webscripts with curl if necessary.

Example of a task that reloads an Alfresco Share webscript:

```
<target name="deploy-share-webscripts" depends="Share: Copy files" description="Refreshes the list of webscripts">
    <exec executable="curl">
    <arg value="-d"/>
    <arg value="reset=on"/>
    <arg value="http://admin:admin@${share.web.url}/page/console?reset=webscripts"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Appending the copying part of the ant task (the src-dirs are declared as properties in the beginning of the buildfile):

```
    <echo message="- Copying java classes" />
    <copy todir="${warWebappTargetClasses}" overwrite="false" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="${warTargetJavaDir}" />
    </copy>

    <echo message="- Copying resource files" />
    <copy todir="${warWebappTargetClasses}" overwrite="false" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="${warSrcResourcesDir}" >
            <include name="**/model/*"/>
            <include name="**/templates/**/*"/>
            <include name="**/custom-model-context.xml"/>
            <include name="**/web-client-config-custom.xml"/>
            <include name="**/webclient.properties"/>
            <include name="**/aka-model-resourcebundle*"/>
            <include name="log4j.properties"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <echo message="- Copying resource files from amp into war for quick deployment." />
    <copy todir="${warWebappTargetClasses}" overwrite="false" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="${projectAmpResourcesSrcDir}" />
        <fileset dir="${projectAmpClassesDir}" />

        <fileset dir="${listmanagerAmpResourcesSrcDir}" />

    </copy>

    <echo message="- Copying config files from amp into war for quick deployment." />
    <copy todir="${warWebappTargetClasses}\alfresco\module\Project-amp\" overwrite="false" verbose="true">

        <fileset dir="${projectAmpConfigSrcDir}" />


    </copy>
</target>
```

I use the maven alfresco lifecycle http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Managing_Alfresco_Lifecyle_with_Maven for my setup, which also speeds up things. I sure a lot can be added to this topic.

Comment: Apart of the class reloading (which is less important to me at this stage), what you mean is to create an Ant task which copies extension resources into Share's deployment folder within Tomcat, am I wrong? For example, client side resources would be copied into **tomcat/webapps/share/WebContent/my_resources_folder/...**, or a custom page into **tomcat/webapps/share/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-data/pages/my_custom_page.xml**. If it is what you mean, do have an example of such Ant task? :)

Comment: Ok, added the copy part to my answer, since the code formatting in the comment section was not ideal...

Comment: One more question @erik-b, when you talk about "target folder" what do you exactly mean?

Comment: @AlejandroGarcíaSeco, I'm referencing the output folder for the build, aka the classpath. This is where tomcat looks for the files in runtime. I named it target since thats the default name of the output folder when using maven. For you its probably the bin folder or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid copying the webscripts to the tomcat by configuring additional paths for tomcats shared classloader. This is a setting in `tomcat/conf/catalina.properties`. I set this directly to the projects source directory so there is no need for the compile step.

```
shared.loader=${catalina.home}/shared/classes,${catalina.home}/shared/lib/*.jar,\
/path/to/my/dashlet/src/main/resources,\
```

I also have the following settings in `shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml` to enable automatic refresh of templates and webscripts.

```
<alfresco-config>
    <!-- Global config section -->
    <config replace="true">
        <flags>
            <!-- Developer debugging setting - DEBUG mode for client scripts in the browser -->
            <client-debug>true</client-debug>

            <!-- LOGGING can be toggled at runtime when in DEBUG mode (Ctrl, Ctrl, Shift, Shift).
                 This flag automatically activates logging on page load. -->
            <client-debug-autologging>false</client-debug-autologging>
        </flags>
    </config>

    <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="WebFramework">
        <web-framework>
            <!-- Autowire Runtime Settings -->
            <autowire>
                <!--
                    Developers can set mode to 'production' or 'development' (to disable; SpringSurf caches,
                    FreeMarker template caching and Rhino JavaScript compilation.)
                -->
                <mode>development</mode>
            </autowire>
        </web-framework>
    </config>
</alfresco-config>
```

Comment: As far as I understand, that's more related to server side webscripts development (correct  me if I'm wrong). My question was more focused on client side resources like JavaScript widgets. Anyway what you have provided is very useful and I'll incorporate it to my development environment. Thanks.

Comment: @AlejandroGarcíaSeco: At least for dashlets the client-side part is also packaged inside the jar and is then available on the classpath. Setting the shared classloader to your source directory removes the need for copying and packaging. I'm not sure if the second part of my answer is needed in your case, it might be that it also disables some caching of classpath resources.

Comment: I have been trying out your suggestion but unfortunately doesn't work properly for me. I'm having exceptions when the Spring context is initialized as per of some custom evaluators, I have been trying to sort it out but I wasn't able to find a straight forward solution. I'll try it again further as I cannot spend more time on this now. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually working on private instances so I can afford myself to run exploded apps, so any changes are visible immediately for me. I only need to restart tomcat when I change the datamodel, deploy some new java-backed modules or webscripts or similar. Even though some of those can get reloaded live too.